# CoreAudio: How to detect there's no device behind RemoteIO without starting it?

Tags: swift, core-audio, audiounit, remoteio

I'm trying to use `kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO` unit on Catalyst on a Mac where there's no microphone.

The problem is, the whole initialization of bus 1 (that's input) goes fine, including setting the format, even enabling the bus, but then it fails at `AudioOutputUnitStart(unit)` with some obscure error `-66628` that's not even listed on [osstatus.com](https://osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-66628).

However, if I start the unit with only the output bus 0, then it runs fine and plays my audio.

So, is there an easy way to detect the situation when there's no device behind RemoteIO without enumerating all the devices? Just by trying some function (set or get a parameter?) that will definitely fail.

Here is my code:

```swift
    // Instantiate the unit
    var desc = AudioComponentDescription(componentType: kAudioUnitType_Output, componentSubType: kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO, componentManufacturer: kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple, componentFlags: 0, componentFlagsMask: 0)
    let comp = AudioComponentFindNext(nil, &desc)!
    var unit: AudioUnit!
    NotError(AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &unit), 51000)

    // Set maximum buffer size as recommended by Apple
    var maxFramesPerSlice = UInt32(Self.maxFramesPerSlice)
    NotError(AudioUnitSetProperty(unit, kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 1, &maxFramesPerSlice, SizeOf(maxFramesPerSlice)), 51003)

    // Set format and sample rate to the same as hardware output
    var descr = AudioStreamBasicDescription.canonical(isStereo: true, sampleRate: hardwareSampleRate)
    NotError(AudioUnitSetProperty(unit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &descr, SizeOf(descr)), 51022)

    // Set render callback
    var callback = AURenderCallbackStruct(inputProc: stereoInputRenderCallback, inputProcRefCon: Bridge(obj: self))
    NotError(AudioUnitSetProperty(unit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &callback, SizeOf(callback)), 51008)

    // Enable input - required as it's disabled by default
    var enable: UInt32 = 1
    NotError(AudioUnitSetProperty(unit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &enable, SizeOf(enable)), 51021)

    NotError(AudioUnitInitialize(unit), 51007)
```

So it passes all that and only fails with `OSStatus(-66628)` here:

```swift
    NotError(AudioOutputUnitStart(unit), 51009)
```

I think there has to be some way of detecting the absense of the device before trying to start it.

Edit: ideally I'm looking for a cross-platform way (ioS/macOS)

Comment: Perhaps `kAudioDevicePropertyStreamConfiguration` in `kAudioObjectPropertyScopeInput` and check `mBuffers > 0`?

Comment: @sbooth did something similar already. I get the format descriptor on the hardware side of RemoteIO's two buses. If there's no device behind the bus then the format structure is all zeros. On a Mac Pro for example and under Catalyst I get all zeros for the microphone so seems to be working.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working. I posted my suggestion as an answer so it won't be lost.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that checking whether the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` returned for `kAudioDevicePropertyStreamConfiguration, kAudioObjectPropertyScopeInput` has  `mBuffers > 0` will indicate if a device is present.

Comment: Thanks. This requires a deviceID though, I'm not aware of any cross-platform ways of getting the current input deviceID on iOS, Catalyst and macOS. Any suggestions? Been looking for a while.

Comment: You're right about this requiring a device ID. I'm not sure how to get one on iOS. I know you can get a UID from `AVAudioSessionPortDescription` but I'm not sure if it's possible to translate to a device ID (normally on macOS I'd use `kAudioHardwarePropertyTranslateUIDToDevice`) but I don't know if the UIDs are equivalent.